# numpy.bitwise_and.reduce behaving unexpectedly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, reduce, accumulate

The [`ufunc.reduce`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) for numpy.bitwise_and.reduce does not appear to behave properly... am I misusing it?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = [0x211f,0x1013,0x1111]
>>> np.bitwise_or.accumulate(x)
array([ 8479, 12575, 12575])
>>> np.bitwise_and.accumulate(x)
array([8479,   19,   17])
>>> '%04x' % np.bitwise_or.reduce(x)
'311f'
>>> '%04x' % np.bitwise_and.reduce(x)
'0001'
```

The result of `reduce()` should be the last value of `accumulate()` and it's not. What am I missing here?

For the moment, I can work around by using DeMorgan's identity (swapping OR and AND, and inverting input and output):

```
>>> ~np.bitwise_or.reduce(np.invert(x))
17
```

Comment: As of version 1.12.0, you should see the correct value (-1) for the identity of `np.bitwise_and`. See [PR #7373](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/7373). By the way, very cool workaround!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation you provided, `ufunc.reduce` uses `op.identity` as an initial value.

`numpy.bitwise_and.identity` is `1`, not `0xffffffff....` nor `-1`.

```
>>> np.bitwise_and.identity
1
```

So `numpy.bitwise_and.reduce([0x211f,0x1013,0x1111])` is equivalent to:

```
>>> np.bitwise_and(np.bitwise_and(np.bitwise_and(1, 0x211f), 0x1013), 0x1111)
1
>>> 1 & 0x211f & 0x1013 & 0x1111
1
```

---

```
>>> -1 & 0x211f & 0x1013 & 0x1111
17
```

There seems to be no way to specify the initial value according to the documentation. (unlike Python builtin function [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce))

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks. It's a shame ufunc.reduce does not permit an explicit initial value argument.

Comment: @JasonS, Yeah, it would be good if `ufunc.reduce` allow us to specify the initial value.

Comment: Has this changed over the last couple of years?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, What do you mean? Do you get a different result? Which version of numpy do you use?

Comment: @falsetru. Absolutely not. Your answer is very illuminating, which is why I filed [issue #7060](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7060) with numpy. I just wanted to know if anyone else had recognized this deficiency and notified the developers.

Comment: [Issue #7060](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7060) (among others) has been closed by [PR #7373](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/7373). The identity is set to -1 for the correct integer type now.