# How to test if all rows are equal in a numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In numpy, is there a nice idiomatic way of testing if all rows are equal in a 2d array?

I can do something like

```
np.all([np.array_equal(M[0], M[i]) for i in xrange(1,len(M))])
```

This seems to mix python lists with numpy arrays which is ugly and presumably also slow.

Is there a nicer/neater way?

Comment: As I said for a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14859458/2988730), this really needs a proper solution that does not create a temporary array as large as the original (which both of the answers here as well as there do). I will post an answer once I have made the addition to numpy.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One way is to check that every row of the array `arr` is equal to its first row `arr[0]`:

```
(arr == arr[0]).all()
```

Using equality `==` is fine for integer values, but if `arr` contains floating point values you could use [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) instead to check for equality within a given tolerance:

```
np.isclose(a, a[0]).all()
```

If your array contains `NaN` and you want to avoid the tricky `NaN != NaN` issue, you could combine this approach with `np.isnan`:

```
(np.isclose(a, a[0]) | np.isnan(a)).all()
```

Comment: I think this is the fastest way. Thank you.

Comment: Checking for equality, rather than equality to 0 of the difference, is likely to be a tad faster.

Comment: What about `(np.diff(b, 1, 1) == 0).all()`

Comment: @Jaime - thanks for the suggestion, I've edited it into the answer.

Comment: There is now `np.allclose`.

Comment: Also note that `np.isclose` and `np.allclose` (now) allow for NaN equivalence checking (`equal_nan` parameter).

Comment: Could be worth doing `(arr[1:] == arr[0]).all()` to avoid wastefully comparing row 0 against itself. Like the original solution, this only requires that `arr` has at least one row. I think it would be better if it didn't even require that, which you can do with: `arr.size == 0 or (arr[1:]==arr[0]).all()`

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Simply check if the number if unique items in the array are 1:</strike>

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1]*10 for _ in xrange(5)])
>>> len(np.unique(arr)) == 1
True
```

A solution inspired from unutbu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860884/846892):

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1]*10 for _ in xrange(5)])
>>> np.all(np.all(arr == arr[0,:], axis = 1))
True
```

One problem with your code is that you're creating an entire list first before applying `np.all()` on it. Due to that there's no short-circuiting happening in your version, instead of that it would be better if you use Python's `all()` with a generator expression:

**Timing comparisons:**

```
>>> M = arr = np.array([[3]*100] + [[2]*100 for _ in xrange(1000)])
>>> %timeit np.all(np.all(arr == arr[0,:], axis = 1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 272 µs per loop
>>> %timeit (np.diff(M, axis=0) == 0).all()
1000 loops, best of 3: 596 µs per loop
>>> %timeit np.all([np.array_equal(M[0], M[i]) for i in xrange(1,len(M))])
100 loops, best of 3: 10.6 ms per loop
>>> %timeit all(np.array_equal(M[0], M[i]) for i in xrange(1,len(M)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.3 µs per loop

>>> M = arr = np.array([[2]*100 for _ in xrange(1000)])
>>> %timeit np.all(np.all(arr == arr[0,:], axis = 1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 330 µs per loop
>>> %timeit (np.diff(M, axis=0) == 0).all()
1000 loops, best of 3: 594 µs per loop
>>> %timeit np.all([np.array_equal(M[0], M[i]) for i in xrange(1,len(M))])
100 loops, best of 3: 9.51 ms per loop
>>> %timeit all(np.array_equal(M[0], M[i]) for i in xrange(1,len(M)))
100 loops, best of 3: 9.44 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think ajcr's answer is even faster!

Comment: @user2179021 It is taking `650 µs` on my system, so still slower than my second answer.

Comment: Agreed - the second method is faster than mine on my system too.

Comment: Do you think there is a similarly fast way to tell if all the rows are distinct?

Comment: Your first method is actually checking if all items of the array are the same, not if all rows are the same... Try it with `np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])`.

Comment: @Jaime Face-palm, will remove that part soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It is worth mentioning that the [above version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164297/3338479) will not work for multidimensional arrays.

For example: for a three-dimensional square image tensor `img` [256, 256, 3] , we need to check whether the same RGB [256, 256] layers in the image or not.
In this case, we need to use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

`(img == img[:, :, 0, np.newaxis]).all()`

Because simple `img[:, :, 0]` gives us [256, 256], but we need [256, 256, 1] to broadcast through layers.

Answer (score 1):

For Alex's answer about `nan`, we have now,

```
np.isclose([1.0, np.nan], [1.0, np.nan], equal_nan=True)
np.allclose([1.0, np.nan], [1.0, np.nan], equal_nan=True)
```