# Scipy maximum filter for all equal values

Tags: python, scipy, filtering

I want to use scipy's maximum_filter to detect local maximas, but there is one issue. If the filter applies the function on values that are all equal, it returns all of them as local maximas, but I need to have them the opposite way.

An example script:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as sc

ones_matrix = np.ones((6,6))

max_arr = (ones_matrix == sc.maximum_filter(ones_matrix, 3, mode = 'constant'))
print max_arr
```

This returns all True, but I need them as false. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

```
[[ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]]
```

Comment: What about you use `max_arr = (ones_matrix != sc.maximum_filter(ones_matrix, 3, mode = 'constant'))`?

Comment: Can you add a special case for if all of the values in the matrix are equal, and therefore return `False` instead of running `scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter`? I think scipy is doing the "right" thing.

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859458/how-to-check-if-all-values-in-the-columns-of-a-numpy-matrix-are-the-same

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. @BPL's solution works. :)

Comment: @Litwos Ok, I've added my comment as an answer so we can close the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your sentence:

```
max_arr = (ones_matrix == sc.maximum_filter(ones_matrix, 3, mode = 'constant'))
```

for this one:

```
max_arr = (ones_matrix != sc.maximum_filter(ones_matrix, 3, mode = 'constant'))
```