# Numpy and The best way to remove rows with idendical values

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I'm struggling with numpy lib.

I have a tensor of the shape (batch_size, timestep, feature):

For example lets create a dummy:

```
x = np.arange(42).reshape(2,7,3)
#now make some rows have homogeneous values
x[:,::3,:] =0
x[:,::5,:] =2
```

Now I need a **numpyish** way(which is repeatable in **tensorflow**) to remove rows(axis=-2) where all values are the same. So in the end I need a tensor to look like this:

```
[[[ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]
  [12 13 14]]

 [[24 25 26]
  [27 28 29]
  [33 34 35]]]
```

Thanks.
P.S. this is not the same question as to "remove all zero rows". Since here we are talking about rows with homo- values. And this is a bit trickier.

Comment: `numpy` generally won't make ragged arrays, and it's likely without structured input that the `axis = -2` dimensions won't be equal (i.e. if there are more rows to drop in `x[0]` than `x[1]` or vice-versa)

Comment: Also, then `tensorflow` will choke on the same restriction.  Are you sure the same number of rows is always removed from each `axis = 0` dimension?

Comment: No, the number of rows to remove  in each batch is different. :( But you have mentioned this and I realised that I didn't think about  the"ragged array" output....Thanks for the hint. 
But what if we are talking about numpy only (just let's leave the TF out of this for a moment)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if all values in the columns of a numpy matrix are the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859458/how-to-check-if-all-values-in-the-columns-of-a-numpy-matrix-are-the-same)

Comment: The comparison I can make on my own, but the deletion for some reason made things quite harder.

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with losing one dimension (so that your array remains homogeneous), then you can do:

```
x[~np.all(x == x[:, :, 0, np.newaxis], axis=-1)]
# out:
[[ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [12 13 14]
 [24 25 26]
 [27 28 29]
 [33 34 35]]
```

**Credit**: @unutbu's [answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860884/758174), here adapted to one more dimension.

**Why is the 3rd dimension removed**? Imagine if your conditions were such that you wanted to select 2 rows from your first array and 3 from your second: then the result would be heterogeneous, which would have to be stored as a masked array or as a list of arrays.

Comment: Nice oneliner here. Thanks. But what's this newaxis doing in `x[:, :, 0, np.newaxis]` ?

Comment: that's to keep the shapes compatible. Compare: `x[:, :, 0]` vs `x[:, :, 0, np.newaxis]`: the former cannot be compared to `x`, but the latter can. Generally speaking, `np.newaxis` or `None` is used to introduce a new dimension (in our case, the last dimension that was lost). It allows us to cycle that last dimension (equal to 1) during the comparison.

Comment: You could modify it a bit and keep the dimensions consistent.  You have to call `np.all` twice though.  `x[:,~np.all(np.all(x == x[0, :, 0,np.newaxis],axis=-1),axis=0),:]`

Comment: @AeroEngy: by doing that, sure, you enforce the result to be homogeneous, but you possibly violate the conditions (e.g.: in the case where the conditions result in an uneven selection for each "block").

Comment: Damn, this x[:, :, 0, np.newaxis] trick!!! Where the hell can I learn numpy to such a level? All the books are just superficial glosses of basic functionality...

Comment: Yes, that would force even selections per block... I don't know enough his use case to know if that makes sense or not.  I imagine if there is not an even selection then something is wrong

Comment: @coobit: I think you are doing the right things: look for answers on SO and check in the numpy docs -- and then ask good questions like this one, with a nice minimal reproducible example (thank you for that).

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more clever way using only `numpy`.  However, you could just iterate over the 2nd dimension and do a comparison.

```
not_same= []
for n in range(x.shape[1]): # iterate over the 2nd dimension
    # test if it is homogeneous i.e. first value equal all values
    not_same.append(~np.all(x[:,n,:] ==x[0,n,0]))
out = x[:,not_same,:]
```

This gives you:

```
array([[[ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [12, 13, 14]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29],
        [33, 34, 35]]])
```

Comment: As far as I know, the whole purpose of numpy is to avoid manual iteration... But it's something. Thanks.

Comment: @coobit  Agreed but I couldn't think of a way to output x and keep the dimension the same.  See the other answer which collapses one of the dimension.